# Need to add comments during creation a scheduled task in Windows 7

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

When I'm registering a new job in PowerShell, I need to add a comment to a scheduled task. Does any of you know how to do it?

I'm registering the task like this:

```
$T = New-JobTrigger -Once -At $date
Register-ScheduledJob -Name $name -FilePath $scriptPath -Trigger $T
```

Comment: You mean a description? I think you need [`New-ScheduledTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask) or [`Set-ScheduledTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/set-scheduledtask) for that.

Comment: The new-ScheduledTask is not available in win 7, it's only available in win 10. My PS version is 5.1.x Maybe i need to upgrade the version? OR to import some module? Thanks

Comment: Ah, I forgot that the `*-ScheduledTask` cmdlets were introduced with Windows 8. You'll have to resort to the Task Scheduler 2.0 COM API then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update scheduled tasks/jobs in Windows 7 via the [Task Scheduler 2.0 COM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/task-scheduler-objects):

```
$name = 'your_task'

# ... register scheduled job here ...

$sched = New-Object -ComObject 'Schedule.Service'
$sched.Connect()

$jobs = $sched.GetFolder('\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs')
$task = $jobs.GetTask($name)

$def = $task.Definition
$def.RegistrationInfo.Description = 'some description'

$jobs.RegisterTaskDefinition($name, $def, 4, $null, $null, $null) | Out-Null
```

You must assign the task definition to a variable first, otherwise you cannot change its properties. Setting the third parameter of [`RegisterTaskDefinition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/taskfolder-registertaskdefinition) to 4 updates an existing task. Using a value of 6 (create or update) would also be possible, but is not required here.